What's A Pejorative Term For A Man Whose Mother Was In A Harem?
It's for a fictional novel, but in modern reality. Like, "damn your parents didn't see each other equals?" But that intent for any existing word on the topic with a different etymology could be made clear though narrational context. So it's ethical to give me a really good one.

First prince then possibly sultan…or like Ishmael of the Ishmaelites? I think you mean like William the Bastard, aka William the Conqueror, not a "harem" per se.

Depending on how pejorative you want to be, and how acceptable being "in a harem" is, you might consider the old word "whoreson". It means exactly what it looks like, although "whore" was often used for a woman who had sex without marriage, not just one to accepted money for sex. It's very insulting.

Yep, the Bard used it right?

I like this one a lot, I view the inequality in a harem relationship to be one where the wives are used as sex objects, which is akin whore.
I like fils de clébard as well, to accentuate the inequality of the relation between parents.

Bastard is commonly used for your case. It is sometimes considered profane depending on the context (especially definition 1) but it's a perfectly valid English word:
Cambridge Dictionary - Bastard

An unpleasant person:


You lied to me, you bastard!


Old use: A person born to parents who are not married to each other:


He was born in 1798, the bastard son of a country squire and his
mistress.

In your case, definition two would be appropriate, and was (still is in some circles) often used pejoratively.

Women in harems can be married.

I like this and it's the feel I'd like the eventual word to have, but my understanding is that these harems are interpreted as polygamy, which is marriage in a sense.

@StephenBoisvert - There are wives, concubines and other female members of a household in a harem. A woman in a harem can be married, but not necessarily is she married. Perhaps bastard isn't entirely appropriate because some women in a harem are indeed married. But in western societies, at least since medieval times, harems and polygamy have not been acceptable. So there may not be a better term in modern English, and bastard is often pejorative and connotes the harem style licentiousness you seem to be looking for. Perhaps someone will find a better term.

@StephenBoisvert - Love Child is another, more modern term, that is also used. But, like bastard, it means a child from an unmarried couple, nor is it as pejorative as bastard. Love Child : A child whose parents are not married to each other.
